# Does alpha-amylase from different species have different *optimal* conditions?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, enzymes

Do the optimal conditions for the enzyme isoforms differ between species? Specifically, do the optimal pH and temperature for alpha-amylase differ for that enzyme produced by *B. lichiniformis* and *A. orzyae*.

Comment: They **may** differ as different organisms have evolved to live in different environments.